# Incompatible pointer type error using structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to programming. I am trying to learn C and pointers, but it is giving me much trouble.
I got the following error trying to implement a singly linked list.  I searched online, and I couldn't find someone who had an error just like mine, or perhaps I just didn't couldn't make sense of it with my problem.

The following is the error I received:

warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'NODE *'
      (aka 'struct node *') with an expression of type 'struct NODE *'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        NODE* temp = (*l)->head;

```
    NODE* temp = (*l)->head;
```

In main, I passed the address of the variable of type LIST.  So, I thought I had to dereference 'l', to get the address of where the LIST type is located, then I had to dereference with an arrow to get the address of where the NODE is located.  Where am I confused?  I do appreciate the help.

Below you will see the code I have written:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
}NODE;

typedef struct list{
    struct NODE* head;
}LIST;

void insert(LIST** l, int x){

    if((*l)->head == NULL){

      NODE* new_Node = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
      new_Node->next = NULL;
      new_Node->value = x;
    }

    NODE* temp = (*l)->head;

    while(temp->next != NULL){
      temp=temp->next;
    }

    NODE* new_Node = (NODE*) malloc (sizeof(NODE));
    temp->next = new_Node;
    new_Node->next = NULL;
    new_Node->value = x;
}

int main(){

    LIST *l = (LIST*) malloc(sizeof(LIST));

    insert(&l, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your problem is here :

```
typedef struct list
{
     struct NODE* head;
}LIST;
```

just remove `struct` keyword before `NODE`

```
typedef struct list
{
     NODE* head;
}LIST;
```

or

```
typedef struct list
{
     struct node* head;
}LIST;
```

Also you need to initialize the `head` with `NULL` to make this condition to wwork

```
  if((*l)->head == NULL) .....
```

so when you create your list add  `l->head = NULL;`

```
      LIST *l = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
      l->head = NULL;
```

And the last one (i hope) when you create your first node, you forget to assign `head` to it, and return in order not to add the first element twice

```
      if((*l)->head == NULL)
      {

         NODE* new_Node = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
         new_Node->next = NULL;
         new_Node->value = x;
         (*l)->head = new_Node;
         return;
      }
```

And BTW, [don't cast `malloc` results in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2549281)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That was the error. Unfortunately, I traded one error for another.  I have a segfault now that I have to find.

Comment: @Apprentice0 segfault on which line ? Can you debug ?

Comment: I am learning how to use GDB. I will attempt to run the executable with it.

Comment: I got this using GDB, not sure if this will help:   * thread #1: tid = 0x31a93d, 0x0000000100000ecd a.out`insert + 93, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000ecd a.out`insert + 93
a.out`insert + 93:
-> 0x100000ecd:  cmpq   $0x0, 0x8(%rax)
   0x100000ed5:  je     0x100000eec               ; insert + 124
   0x100000edb:  movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax
   0x100000edf:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax

Comment: Thanks, those were the problems.  I assigned it in the other block, but somehow I missed it in the if((*l)->head == NULL) block.  I didn't include the return statement, even though it compiled.  So, I am guessing that two new node would be created with identical values before it left that function.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
typedef struct list{
    struct NODE* head;
}LIST;
```

Should be this:

```
typedef struct list{
    NODE* head;
}LIST;
```

Tested and compiles fine with that change.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `*l` is correct. The problem is with the line:

```
NODE* temp = (*l)->head;
```

The left-hand side is `NODE *`, which is the same as `struct node *`, however the right-hand side is `struct NODE *`.

C is case-sensitive, `struct node` and `struct NODE` are different types. Also, the namespace of struct tags is separate to that of other types, so `NODE` and `struct NODE` are also different types.

I think you meant, in `LIST`'s definition, that `struct NODE* head;` should be `NODE* head;`. There is no warning generated on that line, because in C it's legal to implicitly declare a struct type just by mentioning it (i.e. this line declares the new type `struct NODE` also).

Comment: That was the error.  It compiled without errors; now, I have a "segmentation fault: 11" that I did not expect.

Comment: Your code has logic bugs, try working on that. The first one is that you never initialize the values in `*l`. Pointers don't automatically start off as NULL or anything.

Comment: You probably also want to set `(*l)->head` to the new node you just allocated , and `return` after doing so (in the `if((*l)->head == NULL)` block)

Comment: Wow, I completely goofed up there.  I forgot to assign the new node in that block. Thanks @Matt McNabb  I have no segfaults now.

Comment: consider up-voting helpful answers and accepting one

Answer (score 0):

There is code repetition in your `insert` function. You should not use the `struct` keyword before `NODE` in the second `typedef` statement because `NODE` is already an alias for the type `struct node`. That's why you are getting the warning mentioned in your question. Also, you should not cast the result of `malloc`. Please read this - [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1809377)
I suggest the following changes to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

typedef struct list {
    NODE *head;
} LIST;

void insert(LIST **l, int x) {
    // do not cast the result of malloc.
    // also, do not repeat the type on the rhs.
    // create the new node to be inserted

    NODE *new_Node = malloc(sizeof(*new_Node));
    new_Node->next = NULL;
    new_Node->value = x;

    NODE *temp = (*l)->head;

    // check if the head of the list is empty
    // if yes, simply assign the new node to head
    // and return
    if(temp == NULL) {
        (*l)->head = new_Node;
        return;
    }

    // reach the last node in the list
    while(temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;

    // insert the new node to the end of the list
    temp->next = new_Node;
}

int main(void) {
    LIST *l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
    insert(&l, 5);
    insert(&l, 10);

    // print the value of the head node
    printf("%d\n", l->head->value);

    // print the value of the next node
    printf("%d\n", l->head->next->value);

    NODE *head = l->head;
    NODE *temp = NULL;

    // free the nodes in the list
    while(head != NULL) {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }

    // free the pointer to the 
    // head of the list
    free(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am confused on why you are using *new_Node after size0f in the following line:   NODE *new_Node = malloc(sizeof(*new_Node)); I thought that creating memory for the struct new_Node would go there instead of a pointer type to new_Node?  I would appreciate you helping me understand that part.  Yeah, I was redundant with the code.  Thanks for showing me that inefficiency of mine.

Comment: That's because `sizeof` will infer the type of `(*new_Node)`. Also, it's more maintainable and avoids repeating type. If you were to change the definition of the type `NODE`, the `malloc` statement would still work without the need to change anything.

Comment: Thanks @ajay.  Definitely will use that approach from this moment forward.

Comment: I just signed up, and apparently I can't up vote at the moment. But,  I will keep what you said in mind.  I received much help with this problem, and I appreciate everyone's help.